# How to customize the look and feel of rich faces tab panel

Tags: css, richfaces, customization, look-and-feel

I want to use rich faces tab panel. How do I customize the look and feel of the tabs.

What are the css classes that I must override ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's all in the [Richfaces Developer Guide](http://docs.jboss.org/richfaces/latest_3_3_X/en/devguide/html/rich_tabPanel.html)

[image]